# Navigate tabs with CMD+NUMBER in VSCODE

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out how to assign the CMD(ctrl on pc)+NUMBER behavior in CODE to navigate tabs. Like Chrome or many others...

Can't seem to find anything on the subject.

Would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

All keybindings in VS Code can be edited and configured the way you want. The command you want to rebind has the name `workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1` and goes until `workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex9` for all the possible indexes you can jump to via keyboard.

1. Open VS Keybindings (Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts). This will open two side-by-side documents.
2. Add a new `{ "key": "Cmd+1", "command": "workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex1" }` entry
3. Continue for all indexes you want
4. Save the User Settings file.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for!